# Execute PowerShell cmdlet in C# script

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm tying to use C# to connect to exchange and return the mailbox listing for a particular user. I am able to run this locally in PowerShell, however in the context of the script it's not showing what I expect.

I'm seeing outputs like tmp_1qf14mc3.wiv or tmp_ra1gbenl.ols instead of the mailbox listing.

**Additional notes:**

- I have set up the reference to and imported the namespace of System.Management.Automation;
- I'm running this through Visual Studio 2017, using the IIS Express build
- This uses the .NET Core API project

.

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            // Attempt to get the mailbox listing for the user
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(
                "$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList " + user + ",(ConvertTo-SecureString -String " + pass + " -AsPlainText -Force); " +
                "$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection; " +
                "Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking; " +
                "Get-Mailbox; " +
                "Remove-PSSession $Session");

            // Invoke execution to collect the output
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            // Go through each output returned
            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
            {
                // Dump the output to see what's coming out.
                if (outputItem != null)
                {
                    return new string[] { outputItem.ToString() };
                }
            }
        }

        return new string[] { "Did not get a powershell outputItem" };
```

Comment: when you run this in the shell - do you run elevated? it is likely that this is a user permission issue.

Comment: Yes, I run it as administrator as I also run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned;` at the start.

Comment: try to run your app as elevated too, does that work?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia That didn't work, the output was still "tmp_cvxvy4vc.vhp" but very cool - I never thought to run VS as admin. I suspect this problem has something to do with how C# returns the output of what happens in the script.

Comment: how about `PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Out-String");` ?